# Add features with branches incrementally

Tags: git, github

I'm creating a project where I'd like to have a base branch that is a rudimentary version of the project and allow users to merge additional branches to add features.  How do I avoid merge conflicts? There are likely common lines that change between branches as well as files that are deleted or renamed.

At first, I intended on simply basing each new branch on the previous branch but it occurred to me that someone may want featureA and featureC but not featureB.  Doing it that way would require someone merging featureC to accept featureB as well.

The goal is to have a baseline branch and the user can then merge in

- featureA branch
- featureC branch
- featureN branch

in any combination, so long as they start with the baseline branch, and still end up with working project with no merge conflicts.

Is this possible?

Comment: *"How do I avoid merge conflicts?"* -- you can't.

Comment: You're trying to use `git` as some sort of interface to a an arbitrary menu of configuration choices. Git is not the tool for that.  Maybe you could repurpose something like the Linux kernel configuration UI, or write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to build a plugin framework with hooks so that core features can be extended with custom code. It's not trivial, for sure, but there are a ton of examples out there.

**But git is definitely NOT the right tool for the job.** Even when it thinks it can handle a merge without conflicts, the result might not be functional at all. For example, one merge that removes an "unused" function, and another merge that actually uses that function, aren't in conflict, as far as git is concerned. But the result is runtime errors.